# How to prove that every infinite cardinal $Z$ is equal the countable sum of sets of size $Z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Any infinite cardinal $Z$ can be expressed as a countable union of disjoint sets, each of them has the same size $Z$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You ask about any infinite cardinal $Z$, but the answer (which you seem happy with) assumes $Z$ is the set of integers.  Which is it?  The statement is true for any infinite cardinal $Z$

Comment: Dear Ziko: if you find an answer to be helpful, you are encouraged to accept it (you can accept exactly one answer per question). To accept an answer, you can simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You also get two reputation points for each answer you accept. Soon, with just a little more reputation, you'll also be able to "up-vote" as many answers as you'd like!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Recall that $Z$ and $Z \times \mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality.  It should be *much* easier to work with the second set.

Comment: @ArthurFicher .... I need an explicit proof. If possible

Comment: @ZikoSarbi: Can you think of how to express $Z \times \mathbb{N}$ as the disjoint union of countably many sets each having the same cardinality as $Z$?

Comment: @ArthurFicher I am really sorry to tell you that I can not express it. Could you please give me a proof in general not only for $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @ZikoSarbi: This is how one would prove the general case: reduce it to a case that is much easier!  (Note that I am using $Z$, as you did in your question, and not $\mathbb Z$, the set of integers.)  There are two things that are left to do.  The first is the content of my first comment.  The second is to demonstrate that knowing that one can partition $Z \times \mathbb{N}$ into countable many pairwise disjoint sets each having the same cardinality as $Z$, then the same can be done to $Z$.  (This will use the fact that $Z$ and $Z \times \mathbb N$ have the same cardinality.)

Comment: @ArthurFicher you mean each set is of this form $\mathbb{Z}\times \{n\}$

Comment: @ZikoSarbi: Yes!!

Comment: @ArthurFicher Thanks dear for this tip , excellent

Comment: @ZikoSarbi: You're welcome! My original answer was perhaps a bit obscure, but I'm glad you got it.